# Why does the method of trigonometric substitution using csc,cot,cos vs sin,tan,sec yield different answers when used on definite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

$$I=\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$
As an indefinite integral, I can use either cosecant or secant, leading to simplified integral of either

[image]

It works since cosecant and secant have the same area under the curve over the infinite run since they are the horizontally translated version of each other. As for the negative sign, $a/|a|$ can be positive or negative $a$. But this horizontal translation becomes important when solving a definite integral. Why would using cosecant rather than secant here yield a different answer?

Comment: What do you mean by you can't do this problem using csc, cot and cos?

Comment: I should revise my question. My question is why does using cosecant in this case yield a different answer than using secant (if we were solving a definite integral)?

Comment: Can you provide an example definite integral for which substituting with $\sec$ gives a different result than substituting with $\csc$?

Comment: When you are finding the solution for a definite integral, the upper limit and lower limit, say a and b; they will be for x, not for cosecant or secant. So when you replace x by either of these, the New limits of the integration would accordingly give the same result finally.